# Showing different characters when I convert .doc extenstion file to text format using php

Tags: php

I've word file with .doc extension which have only this content **Test1001**. When I convert this word file it's showing me following characters

```
Y, dXiJ(x(I_TS1EZBmU/xYy5g/GMGeD3Vqq8K)fw9 xrxwrTZaGy8IjbRcXI u3KGnD1NIBs 
RuKV.ELM2fiVvlu8zH (W )6-rCSj id DAIqbJx6kASht(QpmcaSlXP1Mh9MVdDAaVBfJP8AVf 6Q
```

instead of **Test1001**

Do you know why it's showing this characters ?

**I'm using following class:**

```
    private function read_doc() {
        $fileHandle = fopen($this->filename, "r");
        $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($this->filename));   
        $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
        $outtext = "";
        foreach($lines as $thisline)
          {
            $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
            if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
              {
              } else {
                $outtext .= $thisline." ";
              }
          }
         $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
        return $outtext;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word `.doc` formats are **binary** not text, you cannot simply assume they are text as you have done in your PHP.

To get the data out of a Word file, you would need to actually use Word or a library that understands and converts the Word binary format into text.

Most people try to use the `.docx` format that newer versions of Word create as this uses XML inside a zip archive. There are a number of libraries that will handle that format. Such as [PHPOffice](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

For the binary `.doc` format, there is [Docvert](http://static.holloway.co.nz/docvert/) that will convert from `.doc` to HTML on the fly.

Comment: do you know any library that convert this doc file text file ?